# Is it true that an abelian group is cyclic iff every $n$-torsion subgroup is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Obviously if it is cyclic every subgroup, including the torsion subgroups, is cyclic. I'm having trouble figuring if the converse is true.

Comment: Do you mean a *finite* abelian group?

Comment: What is an $n$-torsion subgroup? Your question involves $n$, and you have not said what $n$ is, so it is really difficult to understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I meant the subgroup of elements whose orders divide $n$. It can be defined for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Consider the circle group $\{e^{i\theta}\mid\theta\in [0,2\pi)\}$.

For the finite case, it's true.  For, if $G$ is not cyclic,  it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z_p$.  But then, the $p$-torsion subgroup is not cyclic.

Comment: But $V_4$ is a non-cyclic $2$-torsion subgroup of itself.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok, so do you think it's true,  for finite groups?

Comment: Yes I think so. But I was not really sure what an $n$-torsion subgroup is.